# Are my server files safe? I keep getting weird errors that reference an unknown domain

Tags: python, django, docker, http, security

I'm running a Dockerized Django application with NGINX in a VPS and I keep getting these strange requests which results in an error. This is the sentry error log:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'check.best-proxies.ru'. You may need to add 'check.best-proxies.ru' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. 
/azenv.php
django.security.DisallowedHost
```

I don't even understand why its an "Invalid HTTP_HOST header" error. This has been happening for a few days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are safe

Somebody's trying to connect to your server with an url like `https:// check.best-proxies.ru/azenv.php`

IF this is a hostname that you want to allow, then  add it to ALLOWED_HOSTS in your django settings file.

But as you have a site, that is a django site and somebody tries to get a php file I assume, this is just somebody trying to find vulnerabilities on your server.

What I would do (not sure this is easy to be done in your docker setup)
is to add a default nginx configurations for host names, that are not the ones you allow in django `ALLOWED_HOSTS` hosts and let this default log into a different file. Configure it to return 404 for any url being passed

This will keep your application logs clean and should reduce CPU slightly, as nginx can handle this faster than your django application server.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit my NGINX config so it won't even reach Django.